# Difference between collaborator and contributor

Tags: github

In github, I often see these terms and in many cases they are used interchangeably. Can someone please explain the difference between a contributor and a collaborator?

Comment: You may want to read https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/

Comment: Also: https://opensource.stackexchange.com/a/10108

Answer (score 44, accepted):

From the [GitHub Open Source Guide](https://opensource.guide/how-to-contribute/#anatomy-of-an-open-source-project) and [GitHub Help](https://help.github.com/articles/adding-outside-collaborators-to-repositories-in-your-organization/).

- **Author:** The person/s or organization that created the project
- **Owner:** The person/s who has administrative ownership over the organization or repository (not always the same as the original author)
- **Maintainers:** Contributors who are responsible for driving the vision and managing the organizational aspects of the project. (They may also be authors or owners of the project.)
- **Contributors:** Everyone who has contributed something back to the project.
- **Community Members:** People who use the project. They might be active in conversations or express their opinion on the project’s direction.
- An ***outside collaborator*** is a person who isn't explicitly a member of your organization, but who has Read, Write, or Admin permissions to one or more repositories in your organization.

Comment: GitHub defines a Contributor as: "This user has previously committed to the <repo name> repository." I think that generally means a merged pull request (In other words, a contributor is more than someone who "wants to contribute," but someone who has contributed already). Minor point.

Comment: @Nateowami I agree with you as I have tested it out. After my pull request was merged, I was granted as a "Contributor".

Comment: I'm pretty sure Author is just an issue starter (equivalent to OP and TS).