# What is the difference between GitHub Contributor and Member?

Tags: github

I am part of the GitHub Repository Contributor team for one of the repo in my organization, but my name is not displayed in the Member (see the image below). Is the Member same as Github Community member? Otherwise what is the difference between the Contributor and Member and Community Member?

Check this image of a tab on GitHub to understand my question further:

[image]

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866799/difference-between-collaborator-and-contributor

Comment: There is no info about Member on the link you added.