# Cant delete collaborator from my repository

Tags: github

I have made a new github account with this email

**example@gmail.com**

but I had setup this same email for commiting in another account.

Now, when I commited to my account again it commited with the name of the new account.

My commits were from example@gmail.com

Now I setup again the email and my commits are from my first account, but it seems that I cant delete this new account contribution from my repo, I went to collaborators with my main account and I cant get rid of that commit that email did.

Im getting this advice

```
This repository doesn’t have any collaborators yet. Use the form below to add a collaborator.
```

But indeed I have a collaborator in my repo with the email example@gmail.com (the new account)

Is this a bug from github side?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure you aren't confusing contributors and collaborators? See https://stackoverflow.com/q/28866799/354577

Comment: I cant get rid of that collaborator from my git project , and its me with another account but it has more than 8k lines of code commited and I dont want a random account to be there with a commit

Comment: oh wow, I just found out that I cant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44563131/removing-contributor-from-github-com

Comment: Well it's not that you _can't_. It's whether it's worth doing since rewriting history has its implications with Git. Each email address can only be associated with a single GitHub account (though each GitHub account can have several email addresses).